# Is this big complicated thing equal to this? or this? or this?

Tags: c#, operators, idioms

Let's say I'm working with an object of class `thing`.  The way I'm getting this object is a bit wordy:

```
 BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)
```

I'd like to see if this `thing` is equal to `x` or `y` or `z`.  The naive way to write this might be:

```
 BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5) == x ||
 BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5) == y ||
 BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5) == z
```

In some languages I could write something like this:

```
 BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5) == x |= y |= z
```

but C# doesn't allow that.

Is there a C#-idiomatic way to write this test *as a single expression*?

Comment: You could do something like this `if (new yourtype[] { x, y, z }.Contains(BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)))`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, post that as an answer!

Comment: Reading comments below one should emphasize that `==` must likely (unless the functions really return refs to the same object) be overriden in order to do what you want, and overriding and using `Equals` would probably more idiomatic.

Comment: Why does it need to be a single expression?

Comment: @Emrakul, for my own learning.  I *can* rework code to avoid such a requirement, but if I know how to write it as an expression my capabilities increase.

Comment: If you find yourself working with actual code that looks like this, I'd call it a code smell.  It's a clear violation of the [law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter).

Answer (score 46):

Just use a variable:

```
var relative = BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5);
return relative == x || relative == y || relative == z;
```

Or if you want to get fancy with a larger set of things:

```
var relatives = new HashSet<thing>(new[] { x, y, z });
return relatives.Contains(BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5));
```

Comment: I'm specifically asking how to do this *as a single expression*.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. Added another option that should work as a single expression (assuming `relatives` is predetermined earlier)

Comment: You can also inline `relatives` to get "single statement", but it is less readable (also sometimes useful in chained LINQ statements). (just using array is probably enough for 3 items - `(new[] {x,y,z}).Contains...` )

Comment: @Joe: The best answer often solves the problem rather than answering the question.  This **is** the best answer; in C#, the most idiomatic way to compare the result of a function call to multiple things is to assign it to a variable.  Any other method _(such as abusing `Contains()`)_ is non-idiomatic, and will only serve to obfuscate the purpose of your code.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: It's true that "The best answer often solves the problem rather than answering the question", but this should be *explicit* rather than *implicit*. That is -- it's fine to say "there's no idiomatic way to do that as a single expression", but it's not fine to just silently ignore that this is what was asked for. So the originally-posted answer was incomplete.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer and the first approach is 100x more legible than the 2nd.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: using `Contains()` to check for a value in a range of values is most certainly acceptable and I would argue commonly used too.

Answer (score 24):

An extension method would simulate this:

```
public static bool EqualsAny(this Thing thing, params object[] compare)
{
    return compare.Contains(thing);
}

bool result = BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5).EqualsAny(x, y, z);
```

C# doesn't have a default syntax for such an OR-like comparison afaik.

Comment: you could make this generic as well

Comment: Keep in mind that `Contains` uses `Equals` and not `==`, which is what OP is using. These are not always the same.

Comment: @Rubixus I know for Java, that's true, but IIRC, they are for C#. Or maybe I'm just thinking of strings

Comment: @ColeJohnson By default, Equals and == are the same for reference types (both use ReferenceEquals), but Equals is oftentimes overridden.

Comment: If the `this` parameter has type `Thing`, the array should be `params Thing[] compare`. Or you could make the method more general and make the first parameter `object` as well, but I feel the types of the two parameters should agree. But @aw04's suggestion of making it generic makes sense.

Comment: @Rubixus: `==` can be overridden too.  See also [Guidelines for Overloading `Equals()` and `==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx) has another set of guidelines for overriding `Equals` and `==` for reference types. `==` Can be overridden, however "Most reference types, even those that implement the Equals method, should not override the equality operator (==)" and "Override the equality operator (==) if your type is a base type such as a Point, String, BigNumber, and so on"

Comment: @Rubixus You missed the more important part - `Override the Equals method whenever you implement the equality operator (==)`. So anything that has overriden `==` should have also overriden `Equals`. So unless the OP really is looking for reference equality *specifically*, it's fine to use `Equals`. And if he is, he should probably use `ReferenceEquals` anyway :D

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out a collection is one way you could do this.  If you wanted to have a little more flexibility than using `Contains` (which only really lets you test `x.Equals(y)`), and even support chaining by `&=` in additon to `|=`, I'd suggest the `Any` or `All` extension methods built into .NET.

```
var compares = new[] { x, y, z };
var relative = BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5); 

// Simulate |= behavior
return compares.Any(x => relative == x);

// Simulate &= behavior
return compares.All(x => relative == x);

// A more complex test chained by OR
return compares.Any(x => relative.SomeProperty == x.SomeProperty);

// A less readable but one-line approach
return (new [] {x, y, x}).Any(x => BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5) == x);
```

Comment: Note that the last option can eventually execute `NthRelative` N times, which should be avoided if the operation is expensive.

Answer (score 10):

You could put your objects in a `Collection` first and then use `Contains()`.

```
    var relatives = new Collection<Thing> { x, y, z };
    if (relatives.Contains(BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)))
    {
        ...
    }
```

This could be shortened even more (at the sake of readability):

```
if (new Collection<Thing> { x, y, z }.Contains(BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do such stuff in *one expression*? This calls for my *mad LINQ skillz*!

Working sample (http://ideone.com/VNTFnz):

```
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static int getStuff()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        if ((from option in new int[] {1, 2, 3}
                let thing = getStuff()
                where option == thing
                select option).Any())
            System.Console.WriteLine("in the list!");
    }
}
```

Translated for your case, it would be something like this:

```
        if ((from option in new Thing[] {x, y, z}
                let thing = BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)
                where option == thing
                select option).Any())
            System.Console.WriteLine("in the list!");
```

I'm not saying you should do it this way, but hey, you get the boolean result, you can check against any number of values in place of `x`, `y`, and `z`! Also, this doesn't limit you to comparison with `==`, you can use anything you like in its place.

And hey, *one expression*!

Jokes aside, thinking up weird ways of doing what you wanted to do is fun, but you really should put the result of `BigObjectThing.Uncle.PreferredInputStream.NthRelative(5)` into a variable!